# Q: Database Design - Photo gallery

Tags: database, database-design

I did do my research but I don't know am I doing the part right or wrong I discuss with my team before but we end up have a different concept of doing this part.

So here it is:

```
Image
-id
-img_url
-img_thumb_url
-etc

Product
-id
-title

Product_Image
-id
-product_id
-image_id

Gallery
-id
-image_id
```

and versus:

```
Product
-id
-title

Product_image
-id
-product_id
-img_url
-img_thumb_url
-etc

Gallery
-id
-img_url
-img_thumb_url
-etc
```

Comment: Err can at least tell me why before down vote this question?

Comment: Aside from having another table (image) are there any relational differences between the two schemas? I guess the answer is "use the one that works for you". Would it be worth creating some test data so you can check each schema will hold the data you want?

Comment: Is it possible for an image to not belong to a specific product?

Comment: @halfer both way get the data I need, the different relational is one depend on a Image table another one rely on itself, I just like to know which one do you guys prefer ?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes it is possible

Comment: if it's possible for an image not to belong to a product then you need a specific table for images.

Comment: Database design ... to do what? Any requirements? Not that we are doing design or coding for others on SO ... This question is much to broad and opinion based as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your first version expresses that images can exist independently from products, and that an image can be linked to more than one product. So it allows a lot of flexibility.

The only questionable part of the first version is the gallery table. A gallery links to just one image. So an image may be contained in more than one gallery, but a gallery consists of no more than one image. That's not what we would commonly call a gallery, but I don't know your specific requirements.

The common notion of gallery would be expressed in

```
Gallery
id
name

Gallery_item
id
gallery_id
image_id
```

or, if an image may be contained in only one gallery, `Gallery_item` could be left away, and the `gallery_id` added to `Image`.

The second alternative links an image to at most one product. Depending on a `not null` constraint on `product_id`, such an image would need to be linked to a product or not. But the same image will never be linked to more than one product, so if you need that, you'll have to create the same image twice, which would mean an undesirable redundancy. So this is the way to go only if you are sure that you never need the same image for more than one product.

The gallery, in the second alternative, isn't connected with the other two tables. Of course, you could use `img_url` as a common key to link the product images and the gallery image together. But again, a gallery won't contain more than one image, so I'm confused about its purpose.